# Oracle - Script to find all foreign key dependencies in tree format?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some script that return all foreign key dependencies in a tree format.

I've found this one, but isn't tree format:

```
SELECT c.owner, c.table_name, c.constraint_name, level
FROM dba_constraints r, dba_constraints c
WHERE r.owner = c.r_owner
AND r.constraint_name = c.r_constraint_name
START WITH r.owner = 'OWNER_HERE' AND r.table_name = 'TABLE_HERE'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE r.owner = PRIOR c.owner
AND r.table_name = PRIOR c.table_name
ORDER BY level;
```

Is there some way to return it in tree format?

Comment: You want something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3afdedc1914d0f21015ba6dcd5195117) ?

Comment: Perfect! I've tested here and work as I want, thanks! It's easier read in this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting hierachical queries with lpad function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270781/formatting-hierachical-queries-with-lpad-function)

Comment: Yes, also help. I didn't know about this function. I will study it as well. Look like userful. It's the same function used in the link of @PonderStibbons